# Can I have a mathematical equation within a caption?

Tags: equations, captions

I'd like to have an eqnarray environment (or equivalent) within a table caption. If I do this naively,

```
\begin{table*}
  % table stuff
  \caption{\label{tab:my_tab}
    \begin{eqnarray}
      a &=& b \\ c &=& d
    \end{eqnarray}
  }
\end{table*}
```

LaTeX falls over with LaTeX Error: `\begin{table*} ended by \end{eqnarray}`.
How can I get what I want (I don't mind no equation numbers)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you can, if you enclose it in `minipage`:

```
\caption{\label{tab:my_tab}\leavevmode\\\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \begin{align}
    a &= b \\ c &= d
  \end{align}
  \end{minipage}
}
```

- The `\leavevmode\\` is there to make the equation push below the text **Table:**
- As well, notice that `eqnarray` is deprecated and you may use `align` from `\usepackage{amsmath}`.
- And as @David points out, don't forget to make a short caption as well for the List of tables.
- Last point, numbering equations at such place is rather strange, as **barbara** pointed out. You can use `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` to suppress it.

Comment: is a label *really* wanted on the multi-line equation, or (in this case) two labels?  i find that mighty peculiar.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's a matter of the taste of the author, but I'll add a notice on suppressing it.

Comment: @tohecz - This does not seem to be working when I'm trying to use equations in the caption of a tikzpicture (encapsulated inside a figure env). Is there some other way to go about it?

Comment: @TCSGrad The caption has to go outside `tikzpicture` (but inside `figure`). You can ask a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) where you explain that this solution does not work for you. If you construct a Minimal (non)-Working Example, I'm sure we'll manage to solve the problem ;)

Comment: @tohecz - The question with MWE is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-to-have-aligned-equations-in-a-caption-of-a-tikzpicture