# How to have aligned equations in a caption?

Tags: math-mode, captions

The following is my MWE, inspired from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85829/can-i-have-a-mathematical-equation-within-a-caption) (where my query seemed to merit a separate question, so here it is!):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[b]
   \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]           
       % More stuff here - not relevant I think...

  \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption{\label{q}\leavevmode\\\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
         \begin{align*}
            a &= b \\ c &= d
         \end{align*}
      \end{minipage}
   }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

With the above, I'm getting the following error:

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.19    }
```

I'm not sure how to debug this!

Comment: It's called `\leavevmode`, and the second `\begin{align*}` probably should be an `\end{align*}` and you need `amsmath` and don’t forget to include a short version of that (or do you want the equations in the List of Figures?): `\caption[A formula]{…}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `\leavevmode` or the `minipage`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[b]
   \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]           
       % More stuff here - not relevant I think...

  \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption[something]{\label{q}
         \begin{align*}
            a &= b \\ c &= d
        \end{align*}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```