# Equation environment in caption

Tags: equations, captions, minipage

Is it possible to put an equation environment in a table caption? [Here is an outdated answer that does not compile for me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-to-have-aligned-equations-in-a-caption) with the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
     \begin{equation}
        x=y
     \end{equation}
  \end{minipage}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives the error

`! Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }.<inserted text>\par \end{minipage}}
! Paragraph ended before \caption@ydblarg was complete.<to be read again>\par \end{minipage}}`

Comment: Is something stopping you from writing `\caption{$\displaystyle x=y$}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keeping empty square brackets after \caption tag will solve the error:

```
\caption[]{
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
     \begin{equation}
        x=y
     \end{equation}
  \end{minipage}
}
```

Comment: Well, when I tried your code, it for some reason affects the equation counter (always results in the count being ''+1''), so implicitly affecting the overall equation counter.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might suit your need

**Option: 1**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
    ...
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
    \caption[.]{
    \begin{displaymath}
       E=mc^2
    \end{displaymath} That's a great invention}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

to get

[image]

**Option: 2**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
    ...
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
    \caption[.]{\label{q}
           \begin{equation}
               E = mc^2
           \end{equation} That's great invention.}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

to get as follows,

[image]

The advantage with this **Option 2** is that you can even render the various equation environment by simply adding the `amsmath` package, and also get the equation numbering for free!!

As a last note, it is worth mentioning that you will see a **[.]** near the caption, that is just to make the code working.

Comment: Don't use `center` within a table. It adds unwanted vertical spacing. Use the command `\centering` instead.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for pointing out, I shall note that and will adopt my future answers :)