# Aligning equation in figure caption

Tags: equations, captions

I have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}      
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Fig/cross_section.jpg}
\caption{
    Photon's total cross section as a function of energy in Lead. Taken from \cite{phys}. Where:
    \newline
    $\sigma_{p.e.}$ = Atomic photoelectric effect\\
    $\sigma_{Rayleigh}$ = Rayleigh (coherent) scattering\\
    $\sigma_{compton}$= Compton (incoherent) scattering\\
    $\kappa_{nuc}$ = Pair production, nuclear field\\
    $\kappa_{e}$ = Pair production, electron field}
\label{fig:2.1}
\end{figure}
```

I want to make it so all the text is aligned with respect to the = sign. I tried using align but then my code refused to compile. The same happened when i tried using \hspace and do it manually. Can someone help me out or point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Using `\caption` you will get into alignment trouble within `\listoffigures`.

Comment: So, you'll need option to that: `\caption[]{}`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to have aligned equations in a caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129834/5764) The unfortunate part is that [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129836/5764) explains nothing. The principle is that you should use the optional argument of `\caption[..]{...}` in order to avoid moving arguments causing an issue and then use whatever you want in the mandatory argument to align your caption and text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
```

from the `caption` package, and then make sure to pass the optional argument to the `\caption` command so that the corresponding entry in the `\listoffigures` is accounted for appropriately.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}      
\centering
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption[For the list of figures]{
    Photon's total cross section as a function of energy in Lead. Taken from:
    \begin{align*}
    1 & 2\\
    3 & 4
    \end{align*}
    }
\label{fig:2.1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it worked had to add insert the additional \text before the text but once I figured that out, it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `\parbox`. You should also set the subscripts as text. Your subscripts apparently follow whatever is in the figure but subscripts with more than one letter are not recommended. Better use `$\sigma_\text{R}$` for Rayleigh etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,graphicx,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}      
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption[bla]{\parbox{\textwidth}{
Photon's total cross section as a function of energy in Lead. Taken from somewhere:
\begin{align*}
        \sigma_\text{p.e.} &= \text{Atomic photoelectric effect}\\
        \sigma_\text{Rayleigh} &= \text{Rayleigh (coherent) scattering}\\
        \sigma_\text{compton}&= \text{Compton (incoherent) scattering}\\
        \kappa_\text{nuc} &= \text{Pair production, nuclear field}\\
        \kappa_\text{e} &= \text{Pair production, electron field}
\end{align*}
}}
\label{fig:2.1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```