# How to include eqnarray in caption of figure

Tags: math-mode, equations, captions

I want to write a set of equations in a caption of a figure. I implemented the answer of this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85829/can-i-have-a-mathematical-equation-within-a-caption) but it did not work out. The error I got is:

```
 ! Argument of \Hy@tempa has an extra }.
```

For example I want to write:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{test.pdf}
\caption{\leavevmode\\\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \begin{align}
    a &= b \\ c &= d
  \end{align}
  \end{minipage}
}
\end{figure}
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

### EDIT

I want to write a text, and then write the equations.
For example:

```
The equations are:
a = b 
c = d
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to number the equations?

Comment: @egreg, I can simply write the equations in `\begin{eqnarray*}` so as not to number the equations.

Comment: Don't use `eqnarray`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either `\protect` the `minipage` and the `align` or to use the optional argument for caption (which is a good idea if you are going to generate a list of figures to give an entry for the LoF without the equation); loading the caption package also gives you line breaks:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Some explanatory text goes here\\\protect\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\protect\begin{align}
    a &= b \\ c &= d
  \protect\end{align}\protect\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption[text for the LoF]{Some explanatory text goes here\\\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{align}
    a &= b \\ c &= d
  \end{align}\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the equation numbers?

Comment: @po6 So? Write the text. With both my solutions you can add the text. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @egreg that's up to the OP to have them or remove them.

Comment: The first letter of the first word is written next to `Figure 1`, the others are written on a separate lines.

Comment: @po6 Try `\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption[test for the LoF]{Some text\\\protect\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{align}
    a &= b \\ c &= d
  \end{align}\protect\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption[test for the LoF]{Some text $\begin{aligned}[t]
    a &= b \\ c &= d
  \end{aligned}$}
\end{figure}`

Comment: ok, got it! The problem was that I was writing the text right after the `\caption[]`. Now it works, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you don't want the display in the list of figures, so I add an empty short caption and also `singlelinecheck=false` from the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.6\columnwidth]{duck}
\caption[]{This figure illustrates some functions. The equations are
  \begin{align*}
    a &= b \\ c &= d
  \end{align*}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the numbers, use `align*` instead of `align`; ***never*** use `eqnarray`. See [`eqnarray` vs `align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196)

Comment: Can you explain why **never** to use `eqnarray`?

Comment: @po6 See [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196)

Comment: Can you please see the **edit** to the question. I want to add text before the equations.

Comment: @po6 Do you need the equations in the list of figures?

Comment: it doesn't matter since I do not have a `list of figures`.

Comment: @po6 I changed the code.