# equation* in caption*

Tags: equations, captions, subcaption

I have one `equation*` inside `caption*` in `table` as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\center
\caption{This is a sentence.}
\caption*{This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.}
\begin{equation*}
THISEQUATION=THISEQUATION.
\end{equation*}
\caption*{This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.}
\begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
1&2\\
3&4\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I separated the `caption*` above because it cannot include `equation*` inside, so the resultant spacing of `equation*` is incorrect. Is it possible to let the `caption*` have the `equation*` inside?

Comment: Look at [Can I have a mathematical equation within a caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85829/82917) You probably need to provide a short caption explicitly. (Can't test right now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you no need to get `List of Tables`, then try with the below `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\center
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
\caption[.]{This is a sentence.
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
\begin{equation*}
THISEQUATION=THISEQUATION.
\end{equation*}
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.}
\begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
1&2\\
3&4\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```